# Can functions be used in patterns rules to compute the prerequisites?

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to transform the `%` using funtions in the prereq-pattern?

```
$(HTMLS): %.html : $(word 1,$(subst _, ,%)).rhtml lang/$(word 2,$(subst _, ,%))
```

In this state, make looks for `index_de.rhtml`.

If not, is there a way to depend on more than one file dependant on the target name?
In this case, `HTMLS` contains values like `index_fr.html`, `index_en.html`, `index_de.html`.
The template file would be `index.rhtml` and the languages `fr`, `en`, and `de` respectively.
I want `index_fr.html` to change when `lang/fr` or `index.rhtml` changes.

Comment: Did you try this? To me it looks like this will work and is the best answer as long as you don't have to accomodate for a lot of different pattern construction schemes.

Comment: It won't work.  Expansion of functions/variables happens BEFORE pattern rule substitution.

Comment: @MadScientist But under `.SECONDEXPANSION` it should work, no? Correct quoting applied, of course.

Comment: Yes, it can work with `.SECONDEXPANSION`, given correct escaping of `$`.